# Does last man stand rule come into play earlier with retired out's

Tags: rules, cricket

For 'last man stand' cricket matches, would the 'last man stand' rule come into play if all players were out but one and that was including 2 retired out's?

Comment: "Last man stands" is not a form of cricket which is recognised by the ICC, so you'll have to refer to the rules of the competition you're playing in. But in general, out is out - it doesn't matter how you get out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes from my research. 
https://www.lastmanstands.com/rules